# Ferramenta para gerar XPath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Olá, estou fazendo um spider para capturar com XPath alguns dados da web.

Porem a criação de xpath é meio trabalhosa. Alguém conhece alguma forma de treinar XPath? Exemplo; Clico 5 vezes em um link e alguma ferramenta gera o xpath.

Qualquer dica é bem vinda.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiz um compilado das respostas encontradas aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030487/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-xpath-in-google-chrome

### "Chrome Dev Tools"

Ao usar o "Chrome Dev Tools" (Pode acessar clicando com o botão direito em algum elemento e pedir para "inspecionar elemento") você pode clicar com o botão direito no elemento, em seguida "Copiar XPath".

### Add-on para o Chrome.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl

### Console Javascript

Você pode usar também o $x no console javascript do Chrome.

ex: $x("//img")

### XPather

Não cheguei a testar, mas esta ferramenta aparentemente parecer ser o que você quer.

[XPather](http://xpath.alephzarro.com/)

Comment: A idéia do XPather parece ser o que preciso.. mais não consegui instalar no Firefox

Comment: Legal a compilação, Arthur, +1! Já usei muito essa add-on para o Chrome. Adicionei uma resposta com o http://selectorgadget.com -- dá uma olhada caso vc não conheça, é bem legal. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Experimente o bookmarklet [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com).

Ele funciona assim: logo depois que você aciona, você clica numa coisa que você quer capturar. Ele gera um seletor bem genérico, e destaca em amarelo as seções capturadas.

Daí pra frente, você pode refinar a seleção com: 1) clicando numa área destacada pra remover da seleção; ou 2) clicando numa área não destacada pra adicionar a seleção.

Por padrão ele gera um seletor CSS, mas tem um botão XPath para pegar a expressão equivalente em XPath.

Answer (score 1):

Tem um `add-on` para o Firefox que faz consultas `XPath` em uma página, chamado `XPath Checker`.

[Pagina do add-on](https://code.google.com/p/xpathchecker/)

Answer (score 0):

Instalar `xmllint` (ferramente minúscula, normalmente já instalado em linux) e toca a praticar xpath:

```
xmllint --xpath '//symbol' file.xml
```

ou, tratando-se de html:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//table' file.html
```

ou mesmo

```
xmllint --html  --xpath '//a' 'http://a.b.c/index.html' > links.txt
```